# How to Save the Changes of File

Tags: miktex, compiling, texniccenter

I am using `MikTeX` and `TeXnicCenter`.

This is intended to save the file changes. How to compile the LaTeX files, for example `file.tex`, to be indexed pdf files.

For the first time will be compiled into, `file1.pdf`. Further, if there is a `file1.pdf`, it will compile to `file2.pdf` and so on.

Comment: I would add a bat script to your texniccenter to do the moving of the file afterwards. See how to customize the commands of IDE (I am currently not on windows to test it)

Comment: I guess that if you want TeXnicCenter doing this, you will need to ask the TC-maintainer for this feature (or maybe it already exists). I would do such a thing with a `makefile` but that's not what you are asking for.

Comment: I will try any alternative, @zeroth.

Comment: Can you tell me an alternative editor that can do, @LaRiFaRi.

Comment: @LaRiFaRi It should not be necessary to contact the TC-maintainer. There is already implemented an interface to customize commands. One can even call makefiles from within texniccenter.

Comment: Do you really want to save all the PDF files? If you are interested in the version history of your TeX File, you could use subversion or git. If you are just bothered by Acrobat Reader or Windows Explorer blocking writing access to files, think about using Sumatra-PDF.

Comment: I completely agree with @JFMeier... if you want to have a version control, you should use a version control software

Comment: I am waiting for the batch file, @zeroth.

Comment: What if using the command line, for example: `pdflatex file.tex`

Comment: @EdyJo I didn't say I was going to make it... I think you should look into how to create it your-self. There are a multitude of guides how to use bat-scripts. (I am still not on Windows, and don't plan to for quite some time...)

Answer (score 1):

Do you really want to save all the PDF files? If you are interested in the version history of your TeX File, you could use subversion or git. Then, you have a complete history of all the tex-files and can also see the differences between the versions in a condensed form.

If you are just bothered by Acrobat Reader or Windows Explorer blocking writing access to files, think about using Sumatra-PDF or use Tex-Studio with built in PDF viewer.